TV show: First episode features kids sent to a jungle and find a tiger statue that they can later turn into
I remember that there was this TV show I used to watch that had a kid in it. I think in the first episode the kid with his two other friends had found this sciencey place. One of the friends was a black girl while the other was chubby. The science place I think had an orange z logo. The first episode consisted of the kid going through a portal and ending up in a jungle-looking place. The kids look around and end up finding this tiger who can talk and stand on his hind legs I think. The kids run into a big problem and start getting sucked up into a machine to be captured. The kid ends up using this watch thing to turn into the tiger they had met earlier and then after a fight, they go back to the sciencey place, and then the episode ends.

Welcome Rob. When were you a kid? Was it animated or live-action? What language was it in, what country? Please edit to give more details that you can remember, there's a story-idnentification checklist worth checking out to give you a few hints.

Is this Invizimals (2013)...?



The show revolves around ancient extradimensional creatures known as Invizimals and the Z1 unit, a trio of kids who regularly travel to the homeworld of the Invizimals in order to study them or carry out other missions on behalf of an organisation called the Alliance.
The three kids -- a Japanese boy named Hiro, a British boy named Sam, and a (dark-skinned) Brazilian girl named Lima -- report directly to a scientist named Kenichi Nakamura and his assistant, Jazmin Nayar. They travel to the Invizimals' world through a Stargate-like portal in Kenichi's laboratory and wear bracer-like devices called Z-coms on their left forearms.
In episode 1, "The Alliance I," the kids travel to a jungle in the Invizimals' world, where they meet an Invizimal named Tigershark, who looks like a hybrid of a tiger and a shark, stands on his hind legs, and can talk. In episode 2, "The Alliance II," Tigershark gives Hiro a crystal and the kids visit a tomb-like chamber in the jungle, which has ancient inscriptions on the walls, including one resembling Tigershark's face. In episode 3, "The Alliance III," Hiro discovers that he can transform into a duplicate of Tigershark by merging the crystal Tigershark gave him with his Z-com. He then uses this ability to fight some robot antagonists called Xtractors, which were using technology to turn Invizimals into energy and absorb them, similar to the way Ghostbusters capture ghosts with their traps. After defeating the Xtractors, the kids return to Kenichi's lab.
As the titles of those episodes suggest, it was a three-part storyline, so I'm guessing you saw all three episodes (which were each about twenty minutes long) rather than just one.



